# Output error when trying to install packages

Tags: atom-editor

When I try to install any packages at all the program shows an error. I have provided the error output below. I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall the editor to see if that out work but it unfortunately didnt. I also tried to look it up online to see if there were any solutions but was unable to find any. What shall I do to fix this error?

```
> prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js


C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.39.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --build_v8_with_gn=false )  else (node "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.39.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --build_v8_with_gn=false ) 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty-agent.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt\build\deps\winpty\src\winpty.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=3.1.10 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.39.1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.39.1\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.39.1\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--build_v8_with_gn=false"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb\node_modules\platformio-ide-terminal\node_modules\node-pty-prebuilt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-119627-27096-1uti3m9.wklb No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install: `prebuild-install || node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-pty-prebuilt@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\.atom\.apm\_logs\2019-07-26T23_05_19_362Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update, August 20, 2019**

The issue was fixed in [Atom v1.40.1](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.40.1)

**Old answer**

The said package is currently not working with Atom v1.39, since it includes a major update for the underlying Electron framework.

You can try and rebuild some of the package's native modules. To do so, run `apm rebuild` inside the `~/.atom/packages/platformio-ide-terminal` folder.

If that doesn't work, a workaround is to downgrade Atom to v1.38.x and wait for a fix. You can follow this [discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-install-platformio-ide-terminal-2-9-1-on-atom/67012/13) or subscribe to the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/19705) for updates.